# rabbitmq in NAT environment

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a distributed system with client-server style as following:

```
1.Server A deployed on Cloud
2.Many Client C1-CN deployed in customer ENV,which may be behind NAT.
3.Server A need to Notify Client to do some operations.
```

I have surveyed a little on RabbitMQ,basically i want to know whether it will work as:

```
1.Server A publish event to RabbitMQ queue(each queue for each client)
2.Once event published, Client will get notified and do some operations by parse the message?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have many client programs that need to be notified of something.  These clients will be behind a firewall so you cannot directly connect to them from the server.

Yes RabbitMQ will work.  Set it up on your server and make sure it is reachable over the internet (you will have to open port 5762 in your firewall.  Make sure there is some security regarding connections to the MQ server so that only the clients you want can connect to it.  You will then publish messages to the MQ server, presumably to an exchange that will be responsible for distributing messages to the queues.  Your clients will connect to RabbitMQ and consume a queue.  They should consume in a Thread that will wait for messages to come in and process them as needed.

Comment: @ robthewolf, thanks. Yes.My server with RabbitMQ will reside on public server,but clients reside behind firewall.Server need to notify client if something happened. So according to your comment,it seems work to resolve NAT issue.I will check it in my ENV.

Comment: @SimonWang Hi from 2016! Just wanted to thank you for asking this question. So, thank you very much!